# Simple way to only allow one thread access to resource in C#?

Tags: c#, idisposable

How can I replace this code:

```
try
{
    lock (lockForSomethingInUse)
    {
        somethingInUse = true;
        // use it
    }
}
finally
{
    somethingInUse = false;
}
```

With:

```
using (lockForSomething)
{
   // use it
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the lock-statement? `lock(lockForSomethingInUse) { ... }`

Comment: What is the problem when you using lock as you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `lock` and be able to know whether lock is actually acquired at the moment with using only one statement/variable, you can try using following classes. They won't win you any awards for readability, but they allow you to use `using` for locking as you wanted.

```
class DisposableLock
{
    public bool IsAcquired { get; set; }

    class Handle : IDisposable
    {
        private DisposableLock parent;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            parent.IsAcquired = false;
            Monitor.Exit(parent);
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Acquire()
    {
        var handle = new Handle();
        handle.parent = this;
        handle.parent.IsAcquired = true;
        Monitor.Enter(this);
        return handle;
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
DisposableLock lockForSomething = new DisposableLock();
// ...

using (lockForSomething.Acquire())
{
// do something
}
```

You can then use `lockForSomething.IsAcquired` in some other place to check if resource is being used. The inner class implementing `IDisposable` is to make sure you won't by accident use `using (lockForSomething)`.

Answer (score 4):

`lock()` already generates try/finally block under the hood so just remove it and all would be fine

Comment: looks like question was changed since initialy there was not mentioned `with using(lockForSomething)` but `with lock(lockForSomething)`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
using (lockForSomething) 
{ 
   // use it 
}
```

Implies that lockForSomething is disposed when the using code block exits.  Unless lockForSomething belongs to a broader scope (no no!), then there is no way a different thread can access it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't fail even if the exception happen, because:

```
lock (x) ...
```

is the same as:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try {
   ...
}
finally {
   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```

[The lock statement on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)